# What paper type to use to print an image of a painting to look realistic

Tags: print-design, painting

Apologies if I'm in the wrong place.

I took an image of a painting I have done and wish to print and frame a number of copies.

The painting was done with oil painting on a canvas. I would like to print them and for them to look as similar to the real thing as possible. I'm unsure of what paper to print on and where to get them printed.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paper isn't your only problem, you should also use printing method which can produce rich enough colors which do not get bleak or detoriate otherwise too soon. The paper must be archive quality one without usual color eating chemicals.

People who try to earn money with printed copies of art have about 30 years ago started to call capable enough printing methods Giclee Printing. Originally it was a business name, but today it means printing with inkjet printer. The printer uses pigment colors, ordinary CMYK printing isn't colorful enough. The paper is up to the task. It doesn't suck the inks nor disintegrate the color chemically.

Search for Giclee printing to read more. Start from this: https://tracylizottestudios.com/blog/2018/07/giclee-print-vs-digital-print-which-is-better

Unfortunately we cannot recommend here commercial services, but it's not expensive to make a test run to see if one prints well enough. Direct sunlight or a solarium lamp should reveal quite soon if the colors fade in light.

Many of us surely have seen movie "The ultimate disaster movie" where Mr. Bean makes a famous painting (=Whistler's Mother) dirty, cleans it but removes also the paint. Restoring it with a normal pen wasn't good enough, but Mr. Bean made a fully plausible replica by covering up a 1:1 poster with his improvised special varnish.

Covering up with a special varnish isn't fully a fiction. Giclee printing cannot create the 3D texture of brush strokes. To get that texture one can manually brush along the real stroke lines transparent but refractive enough and non-spreading material which recreates the thickness of the strokes to some degree. You'll find easily several receipes how to use  acrylic gel for that purpose. This is one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2FdBGf_3Us It contains many tricks for making printed copies to look unique and generally being more than only prints.

I guess one must be quite patient and know something of real painting (unlike Mr. Bean) to get plausible results.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, appreciate the Mr Bean comments too :L

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for canvas rather than paper.

Search "picture on canvas", there are a million places that offer the service, from $£€ 25 for small, thin canvas to 3 or 400 for a 'museum-quality' canvas.

Some services will send you samples of their materials before you commit. Some higher-end services will even print small samples of the very image you want them to print.
You do get what you pay for, although if you're going for the high end, find somewhere local you can actually visit, rather than just use an online service.

Comment: One thing I don't like though is when you print canvas texture on top of another canvas texture. Same thing with paper texture printed on heavily textured paper. To me it's not aesthetically pleasing because it reveals the digital nature of the process. If you are to print on a textured surface I would recommend trying to remove the texture from the original before printing. But it's just my personal taste.

Comment: @Wolff - tbh, I do a lot of prints to canvas… but none of them are from canvas originals, so it's not an issue I ever actually have to deal with.